# Appcompat v21. How to collapse SearchView by BackButton

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview

With old appcompat we used `SearchView` in `ActionBar` and When I press Back Button I would collapse the `SearchView`.

But now I switched to `Appcompat v21` and use `ToolBar` instead of it. But now `SearchView` does not collapse when I  press Back button.

How can I solve this problem?

Best Regards.

Comment: Solved it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924445/searchview-not-closing-correctly-on-first-back-press-its-only-loosing-focus/30561597#30561597

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I solved it as follow:
1- let your activity or fragment implements SearchView.OnFocusChangeListener
2- add `mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(this);`
3- add

```
@Override
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!hasFocus) {
         MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);
    }
}
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
searchItem.collapseActionView();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite the onBackPressed() Method:

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
     finish();
}
```

This should do the trick.